# How to copy CCSprite in Cocos2d for Android?

Tags: java, android, sprite, cocos2d-x

To load sprite twice is terrible decision of course.

Is there way that works better than this one?

```
 firstSprite = CCSprite.sprite("Sprite.png");
 secondSprite = CCSprite.sprite(firstSprite.getTexture());
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Java version also supports this method.  The texture rect is important.

```
secondSprite = CCSprite.sprite( firstSprite.getTexture(), firstSprite.getTextureRect() );
```